# Installing mobile apps on a car board computer

Tags: honda, accord, computer, dashboard, navigation

I'm an owner of a Honda Accord 2011 and I'm wondering whether it's possible to install mobile apps on my onboard car computer. It would help me because my manufacturer installed a default navigation application which doesn't automatically update roadmaps, doesn't warn me about speedcams, and doesn't compute live traffic.

For every map update I have to go to see my manufacturer which makes my wallet thinner, unfortunately.

It would be a nice idea to install my own application. In these days it would be unthinkable to not have this option.

Now, I'm using my phone next to my board computer. That's a bit strange at least.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you question correctly you want to install your own applications on your on-board computer. To do this you would need extensive reverse engineering and software development knowledge. You are looking at hundreds and most possibly thousands of man hours. You would be better of fitting a system designed with everything you need.

I would say these are the best options:

1. Replace the on-board computer with an alternative aftermarket system. Systems such as Android Auto or Apple CarPlay by manufactures such as Pioneer, Alpine, Sony, Kenwood etc.
   There might even be a kit available that is plug and play.
   If there isn't a plug and play kit modifying the dashboard and making your own faceplate would take far far less time than modifying the current system. I have personally done this by using 3D printing or by making a new faceplate out of fibreglass and filler.
2. Feed a video and audio input into the onboard computer and use a in car computer or phone etc. Again there may be a plug and play kit for this depending on your onboard computer.
   If there isn't it still may be possible, if there is an option for a reverse camera you can use this and then use a CAN Bus jammer to fool the computer into letting you watch the input at all times.
   If there isn't either of the above you will have to do a bit of hacking to the computer, most likely the controller and the screen will be on separate PCBs, you can hack into the video inputs into the screen and feed your own input, you would then have to feed in a sound input and switch this at the correct time.
3. The manufacture may have a retrofit kit available for your vehicle. If a newer model of your car is available with the same style dash but different on board computer with something like CarPlay etc you should be able to install this.

Comment: An aftermarket device that supports Android Auto or Apple Car Play or both would be the easiest option, I think.  It would be an interface that the OP is used to, and should be available for a popular car like an Accord.